# .NET Core rc2 WebAPI with index.html as default page

Tags: asp.net-core

I have set up an empty WebAPI project with `.NET Core rc2` and have it wired up with `Angular2 rc1`. Angular will handle everything view related and the WebAPI is the backend.

When I start the app by default it comes up with `localhost:4578/api/values` from the default API controller as startpage.

However, I want it to show `index.html` by default which is located in `wwwroot` and is hosting my `Angular2` app.

In `Startup.cs` the `Configure` method looks like this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();

        app.Run(ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Response.Redirect("/index.html");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });
    }
```

`app.UseStaticFiles` and the `app.Run` lambda need to be in place for the manual redirect to `index.html` to work but it still comes up with `/api/values` as default start page.

I know that for debugging purposes I can change the start page easily but I want to change it such that when I host it it always serves `index.html` as start page.

How can I change this?

Comment: I notice that simply redirects to index.html.  I am pretty much at the same point you are and I'm wondering how to get it to load index.html as a default route.

Comment: In my case  app.UseDefaultFiles(); is showing error? any solution??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When creating a new empty WebAPI project, the launchsettings.json file points to api/values by default.  To change it, go to the launchsettings.json file in your project:

[image]

and change the launchUrl value to: http://localhost:4578 (from http://localhost:4578/api/values).

Comment: Still not routing my HTML page i am using ASP.NET Web API MVC Core project? Any Suggestion?

Comment: Better yet, do not enter anything for launchUrl, leave it as empty string like: "launchUrl": ""  This way, the server will launch the site at localhost via the port configured in the project > properties > Debug > Web Server Settings and as long as you include app.UseDefaultFiles() and UseMvc() your default page will be served up.

Comment: have same issue, html page is blank after these settings.