# .NET Core 3.x Add Startup View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a WebApi that I have been using for a .NET Core 3.1 project. It works fine, but when I fire it up it always gives me the JSON of the default controller determined in 'launchSettings.json'. How can I add a very basic index.html that i can put some basic company information.

I don't think enabling MVC is necessary, because I just need a static web page. Currently the file is in the root level of my project. I didn't get a wwwroot folder when I created the project, so not sure if that's necessary or not.

What I've tried:
Changing "launchUrl" node in "launchSettings" to a blank string.
Renamed file to default.html

References:
This post doesn't help as .NET Core has changed so much. (I tried it exactly) 
[.NET Core rc2 WebAPI with index.html as default page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770131/net-core-rc2-webapi-with-index-html-as-default-page)

Anything helps.

Thanks!

Comment: did you add static files to your request pipeline in `Startup`?

Comment: Yes I had it, but your comment made me think I was heading in the right direction. I kept using Google Foo - I *did* need the wwwroot folder. And I also had to call UseDefaultFiles() in my configuration method. I would say this is solved.